# Confused with wpf ComboBox DisplayMemberPath,SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath

Tags: wpf

I have always struggled with those comboBox properties

1. DisplayMemberPath
2. SelectedValue
3. SelectedValuePath

I am building a master detail form .

1. ComboBox filled with Customers
2. User Selects a Customer in Combo
3. All the textBoxes  EG Fills correctly

The problem I am having I have made it work but I don't understand those properties and the differences.
Is there a noddy example explaining what they do?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I think we can understand this better with an example. See this class:

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the following xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employees}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

`DisplayMemberPath` points to the `Name` property, so the value displayed in the `ComboBox` and the `Employee` entries contained in the drop down list, will be the `Name` property of the `Employee` object.

To understand the other two, you should first understand `SelectedItem`. `SelectedItem` will return the currently selected `Employee` object from the `ComboBox`. You can also assign `SelectedItem` with an `Employee` object to set the current selection in the `ComboBox`.

`SelectedValuePath` points to `Id`, which means you can get the `Id` of currently selected `Employee` by using `SelectedValue`. You can also set the currently selected `Employee` in the `ComboBox` by setting the `SelectedValue` to an `Id` (which we assume will be present in the `Employees` list).

Comment: This is the most concise and easiest to understand explanation of these concepts that I've seen.

Comment: NB: This sample would not work, because `Id` and `Name` have to be properties, not class fields.

Comment: You are right. The class was just meant to show pseudo code. Fixed it.

Comment: @Yogesh IMO, `for me`, this is better, more concise and easier to understand than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454/1232087). I said `for me` since we all have different ways of understanding things. Maybe, the other answer is better to understand for some other readers.