# Under SelectionChanged read out the underlying data from a List

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Im busy with my app and i walked in some problems when i click on a photo in my listbox PhotoFeed.

I got 1 List<> with in it the strings UrlTumb and UrlFull.

I got 1 ListBox with in it a WrapPanel filled with images wich i set the Image.Source from my UrlTumb.

What my problem is when i click on a photo in my listbox i want to navigate to a new page and display there the original image (UrlFull) now i can only get my UrlTumb from my Image.Source but i want my UrlFull which is stored in the List. Now is my question how do i obtain the UrlFull. So how can i back trace which item i clicked and get the UrlFull from that item so i can send it with my NavigationService.Navigate

I can do it on an dirty way and create an invisible textblock besides the image in my ListBox and put the UrlFull in there but i would like to do it in a proper way

So what do i place in the ????? spot in this line

```
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PhotoInfo.xaml?urlfull={0}", ????? , UriKind.Relative));
```

Greetings Cn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options:

1. Use selected item's index `listBox.SelectedIndex` to get the index
   of the selected property which will correspond to the index in your
   source (it might not if you filter the collection using collection
   source, but I think that is not the case)
2. Use selected item `listBox.SelectedItem` this will return the
   SelectedItem which will contain your object. (Note, that if your
   selection mode set to multiple, this will return only the firstly
   selected item)
3. Use `SelectemItems`. It will allow you to get an array of selected
   items (Note: this should be normally used only when your list's
   selection mode is set to multiple)
4. Use `SelectedValue`, which will contain the value of the SelectedItem
   (this will save you and extra step.
5. Use arguments of the Selection changed event AddedItems.

Bellow is the code snippet of 3 options above. x, y, z will all be your selected names (e.g. "Mike")

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
         SelectionChanged="NameChanged" />
```

Code behind:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    private List<Person> people = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person{Name = "Lewis"},
            new Person{Name = "Peter"},
            new Person{Name = "Brian"}
        };

    public List<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return this.people;
        }
        set
        {
            this.people = value;
        }
    }

    private void NameChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = this.people[lb.SelectedIndex];
        var y = lb.SelectedItem;
        var z = lb.SelectedItems[0];
        var h = lb.SelectedValue;

        var u = e.AddedItems[0];

        var person = e.AddedItems[0] as Person;
        if (person != null)
        {
            var result = person.Name;
        }
    }
```

For the differences between SelectedValue and SelectedItem refer here [SelectedItem vs SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Comment: var person = e.AddedItems[0] as Person;
        if (person != null)
        {
            var result = person.Name;
        } Totally worked for me :D Ty