# Filling and binding two combobox WPF Caliburn.micro

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, caliburn.micro, dapper

I have this table:

[image]

I use in my project this view Called NewItem and in this view there is two combobox.

[image]

I would like to do this : 
that in the combobox Group there are all DESCRIPTION of table GROUP, and when i choose an item of this description (of first combobox) the second combobox fills of descriptions relating only to that description that I have chosen before.

This is some code:

XAML NewItemView:

```
<ComboBox Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,99,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" x:Name="Group" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}" />
```

The ViewModel code is like:

```
[Export(typeof(IScreen))]
public class NewItemViewModel : Screen
{
   public string SelectedGroup { get; set; }
   public String[] Group { get { return Groups; } }

   [..]


   //Constructor         
   public NewArticleViewModel()
   {
       Groups = GetGroups();
   }


   //Method
   private string[] GetGroups()
   {
     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(StringConn);
     List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

     conn.Open();
     groups = conn.Query<Group>(Q_SELECT_GROUPS,null,null).ToList();
     conn.Close();

     string[] array = new string[groups.Count];

     for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
     {
        array[i] = groups[i].Descripion;
     }

     return array;
   }
}
```

GROUP CLASS IS :

```
public class Group 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripion { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to specify that i use Caliburn.Micro and Dapper for acces'query.

Thank you so much !

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you have tried to accomplish, or are you lost on how to even accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical Master/Detail scenario and there is a typical and easy way to solve it.

I. Instead of only loading descriptions as a `string[]` inside your `GetGroups` method, load the enitre `Group` object or if there is many properties create a view model with only the two needed properties, something like this:

```
class GroupViewModel {
    public int GroupId {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

II. In `NewItemViewModel` add a property for the second ComboBox, let's say

```
class NewItemViewModel {
    private ObservableCollection<SubgroupViewModel> _subgroups;
    public ObservableCollection<SubgroupViewModel> Subgroups
    {
        get {
            if (_subgroups == null)
                _subgroups = new ObservableCollection<SubgroupViewModel>();
            return _subgroups;
        }
        set {
            _subgroups = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Subgroups");
        }
    }
}
```

III. Now in your `NewItemViewModel`, the properties become something like this:

```
class NewItemViewModel {
    public GroupViewModel SelectedGroup
    {
        set {
            var currentlySelected = value;
            // LOAD ALL RELATED Subgroup Descriptions FOR currentlySelected.GroupId;
            Subgroups = // LOADED Subgroup DESCRIPTIONS
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Group { get { return Groups; } }
}
```

I hope you get the idea, this is basic outline of the method. I think you can improve it a bit by leveraging some of [Selectors Important Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) and using other techniques for loading the data.