# Dynamic value not being set in C#.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I have created a method in C#.net 4.0 which returns a dynamic type:

```
public dynamic  GetEntertainmentDetails(int entertainmentId)
    {
        dynamic result = from PE in entities.ProductEntertainments
                     join PM in entities.ProductModels on PE.ProductModelID equals PM.ProductModelID
                     join PMA in entities.ProductMasters on PM.ProductUID equals PMA.ProductUID
                     join PMF in entities.ProductManufactorers on PMA.ManufactorerID equals PMF.ManufactorerID
                     where PE.EntertainmentID == entertainmentId
                     select new { PE.EntertainmentID, PMF.ManufactorerID, PMA.ProductUID, PM.ProductModelID, PE.CDPlayer, PE.CDChanger, PE.DVDPlayer, PE.Radio, PE.AudioSystemRemoteControl, PE.SpeakersFront, PE.SpeakersRear };
        return result;
    }
```

I want to use the results in a method which goes like this:

```
private void DisplayRecord()
    {
        dynamic item = dbContext.GetEntertainmentDetails(entertainmentId);
        this.cmbManufacturer.SelectedValue = item.ManufactorerID;
        this.cmbProducts.SelectedValue = item.ProductUID;
        this.cmbVariant.SelectedValue = item.ProductModelID;
        if (item.CDPlayer == true)
            this.cdPlayerYes.IsChecked = true;
        else
            this.cdPlayerNo.IsChecked = true;

    }
```

But value returned is not being set in cmbManufactorer or any other control. I tested that dyanmic item has values but not sure why are they not being set.

Is it the right way to handle it or am I doing wrong here ?

**Update:**
I am using this code in a WPF application. SelectedValue property can be get/set there for dropdowns.

Comment: any reason for using dynamic? can't var keyword just replace that? LINQ is generally meant for compile time safe

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the value in dropdown like that Since `SelectedValue  is a read only property`
Try like This :-

```
// Assuming item.ManufactorerID is returning the index of selected item:- 

  cmbManufacturer.SelectedIndex  = item.ManufactorerID;
```

Or else if you have `value` of Dropdown then :-

```
 cmbManufacturer.Items.FindByText("PassedValue").Selected = true;
```

Comment: @Pranav.. Selected value can be set there

Comment: if the item.ManufactorerID is returning something which is not in Dropdown then value will not be selected.(or default value 0). for testing just check with  cmbManufacturer.SelectedIndex=2;

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure that returning value is in dropdown list. Here is another example:
 VendData.GetProductColorsByProductColorID_Result colorObject = dbContext.GetProductColorsByID(productColorId); this.cmbManufacturer.SelectedValue = colorObject.ManufactorerID; Here value for cmbManufacturer is being set and displayed.

Comment: I mean definitely it is working for strong types but not for dynamic

Comment: I am not sure because i have not tried with dynamic...but i guess unless `item.ManufactorerID` is returning an INT ..dropdownList should not have any problem ... However Try to cast item.ManufactorerID as Int and check for my sake..

Comment: It is able not item.ManufactorerID to int, but ResultView of the item is showing that there are values in it.

Comment: on checking this link difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath). It seems you might need to use SelectedValue with SelectedValuePath , just for trial you could see what happens when you use SelectedItem

Comment: Let me make myself clear here. It's all not about SelectedValue or SelectedItem. Definitely it works when we have a valid value. It's about how a dynamic object is wrapping the returning results in it. When we set it as 'dynamic s = "1"; cmbABCD.selectedValue=s;' it definitely works, but here scenario is bit different. I am getting a complex result set and wrapping it in a dynamic object and not able to read the returned values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your item.ManufactorerID what kind of value is coming in that.

However dynamic should work if the types are compatable.

For ex:

```
    dynamic s = "Item 3";
    drop1.SelectedValue  = s;
```

Or

```
    dynamic s = 2;
    drop1.SelectedIndex   = s;
```

both works.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got the reason of why was it not working. It's because the GetEntertainmentDetails method was returning a complex result set with an array of items, thus not able to find out the ManufacturerID or any other item. I changed the code as:

```
 public dynamic  GetEntertainmentDetails(int entertainmentId)
    {
        dynamic result = (from PE in entities.ProductEntertainments
                     join PM in entities.ProductModels on PE.ProductModelID equals PM.ProductModelID
                     join PMA in entities.ProductMasters on PM.ProductUID equals PMA.ProductUID
                     join PMF in entities.ProductManufactorers on PMA.ManufactorerID equals PMF.ManufactorerID
                     where PE.EntertainmentID == entertainmentId
                     select new 
                     { 
                         PE.EntertainmentID, 
                         PMF.ManufactorerID, 
                         PMA.ProductUID, 
                         PM.ProductModelID, 
                         PE.CDPlayer, 
                         PE.CDChanger, 
                         PE.DVDPlayer, 
                         PE.Radio, 
                         PE.AudioSystemRemoteControl, 
                         PE.SpeakersFront, 
                         PE.SpeakersRear 
                     }).SingleOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
```

And now I am able to bind every control.