# How to cast a selecteditem in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a *listBox* of color and I want to get the selected color String for *example: Red,yellow*.

The problem is when I get the *selectedItem* I need to cast it to `System.Windows.Media.Color` to get the name and put it into `string` to use it in other case. 
Here is the code I used ,Unfortunately I always get this exception

`Specified cast is not valid`.

System.Windows.Media.Color colo = (System.Windows.Media.Color)listColor.SelectedItem;

Any help would be so appreciated

Comment: What does `listColor.SelectedItem == null ? "<null>" : listColor.SelectedItem.GetType().FullName` evaluate to?

Comment: show the code you use to populate listbox

Comment: _i have a listBox of color_ is not true and the cause of much confusion here. What is inside that listbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XAML a string is so easily converted to a color that you hardly realize they are very different types. In C# you will have to convert it explicitly. Luckily there is a built-in class that can do that:

```
string colorName = (string) listColor.SelectedItem;
Color colorValue = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colorName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **SelectedValue** instead:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color color = (System.Windows.Media.Color)listColor.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: i got the same exception

Comment: @moez Are you sure in your ListBox are stored System.Windows.Media.Colors?

Comment: It's obvious the OP has a listbox full of strings.

Comment: @moez I would suggest you to store System.Windows.Media.Color in your listbox and if you need them as string - convert them as needed.

Comment: when i try to cast it to string i have that exception : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: @moez: In that case, I would like to repeat Sriram's comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

fixed it with

> Blockquote
>    Color colorValue = (Color)((System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)listColor.SelectedValue).GetValue(listColor, null)  ;

Comment: This is the only fix that works - It's a ridiculous leap to get from Color to Color (in the same namespace)

Answer (score 0):

When you add items to your listbox, you actually add `Object`s. Which means that what you see as a text in each of your list item, is the object you added `.ToString()`.

So if you're adding `string`, you'll get back `string`. If you're adding `Color`, you'll get back `Color`.

In your case, you seem to add `string`. Of course you can't cast a string directly in a color, so either you should add the object `Color` to your list, or you should parse the string you get with `SelectedValue` to get a `Color`.

If you want to add directly the object `Color`, you can also use the property `SelectedValuePath` to set the property of your object that will be displayed in the list.

Also you should take a look at this post to see the difference between `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem`: [Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
          Color ChosenColor;
          string SelectedColor= (string)listColor.SelectedItem;;

          ChosenColor=(Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(SelectedColor);
```