# Binding ComboBox SelectedItem using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I have a problem with the **SelectedItem** in my **ComboBox**.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbxSalesPeriods"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SalesPeriods}"
        DisplayMemberPath="displayPeriod"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSalesPeriod}"
        SelectedValuePath="displayPeriod"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

[image: Here is anything ok]
If I open the ComboBox, I see the values.

[image]
**If I select an item, the selected Item won't be shown.**

Has anybody an idea?

In my ViewModel I have these two properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<SalesPeriodVM> SalesPeriods { get; private set; }

private SalesPeriodVM selectedSalesPeriod;
public SalesPeriodVM SelectedSalesPeriod
{
    get { return selectedSalesPeriod; }

    set 
    {
        if (selectedSalesPeriod != value)
        {
            selectedSalesPeriod = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSalesPeriod");
        }
    }
}
```

These are a few properties from the class :

```
public SalesPeriodVO Vo
{
    get { return period; }
}

public int Year
{
    get { return period.Year; }
    set
    {
        if (period.Year != value)
        {
            period.Year = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Year");
        }
    }
}

public int Month
{
    get { return period.Month; }
    set
    {
        if (period.Month != value)
        {
            period.Month = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Month");
        }
    }
}

public string displayPeriod { 
    get
    {
        return this.ToString();
    }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0:D2}.{1}", Month, Year);
}
```

---

**EDIT**:
The Following happens If I remove the Property DisplayMemberPath:
[image]

Comment: You should create a sandbox application. Leave only a combobox, and your viemodels, remove everything else. Then you should try to reproduce this issue. You probably would not be able to. Then compare the two applications, and see which difference could cause such behaviour. I doubt that the issue is in the code you provided. Also notice that your combobox has a name. Check out the code-behind file to see, if there is some code which screws with selection.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You seem to be unnecessarily setting properties on your `ComboBox`. You can remove the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties which have different uses. It might be an idea for you to take a look at the [Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) post here for an explanation of these properties. Try this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbxSalesPeriods"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SalesPeriods}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSalesPeriod}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Furthermore, it is pointless using your `displayPeriod` property, as the WPF Framework would call the `ToString` method automatically for objects that it needs to display that don't have a `DataTemplate` set up for them explicitly.

---

UPDATE >>>

As I can't see all of your code, I cannot tell you what you are doing wrong. Instead, all I can do is to provide you with a complete working example of how to achieve what you want. I've removed the pointless `displayPeriod` property and also your `SalesPeriodVO` property from your class as I know nothing about it... maybe that is the cause of your problem??. Try this:

```
public class SalesPeriodV
{
    private int month, year;

    public int Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set
        {
            if (year != value)
            {
                year = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get { return month; }
        set
        {
            if (month != value)
            {
                month = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Month");
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0:D2}.{1}", Month, Year);
    }

    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added two properties into the view model:

```
private ObservableCollection<SalesPeriodV> salesPeriods = new ObservableCollection<SalesPeriodV>();
public ObservableCollection<SalesPeriodV> SalesPeriods
{
    get { return salesPeriods; }
    set { salesPeriods = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SalesPeriods"); }
}
private SalesPeriodV selectedItem = new SalesPeriodV();
public SalesPeriodV SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set { selectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
}
```

Then initialised the collection with *your* values:

```
SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 3, Year = 2013 } );
SalesPeriods.Add(new SalesPeriodV() { Month = 4, Year = 2013 } );
```

And then data bound *only* these two properties to a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SalesPeriods}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

That's it... that's all you need for a perfectly working example. You should see that the display of the items comes from the `ToString` method *without* your `displayPeriod` property. Hopefully, you can work out your mistakes from this code example.

Comment: This does not answer the question though. Setting those properties should not cause described behaviour in given context.

Comment: I've tried to remove these Properties, but it won't work.
I've edited the first Post.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak I accept that my original answer did *not* provide a complete solution for the user. However, after answering very many of these questions, I have realised that it is fairly rare that an answer can be provided immediately, due to a number of reasons, such as a lack of information or understanding from the question author. As such, I have got into the habit of answering these questions in stages, of which you just saw the first. Now you can see the second stage. Perhaps in the future you could give reputed users the benefit of doubt and save those types of comments for new users?

Comment: @Sheridan, i simply pointed out, that while your suggestions are valid from code-reviewer point of view, they do not attempt to solve the problem at hand. There is no harm in that, is there? I am sorry, if my comment sounded offensive, i did not mean it that way.

Comment: No, there's no problem at all and I did accept your point. Maybe I should have put a disclaimer on the answer saying that it was not yet an attempt to answer the question, but I get so bored of typing the same stuff out again and again. I was just saying that maybe you should trust reputed members to 'do the right thing' on this website, but I didn't mean anything negative by that comment either.

Comment: @Sheridan, "Perhaps in the future you could give reputed users the benefit of doubt and save those types of comments for new users?" -> quite funny :-)

Comment: Maybe I'm blind for the obvious, but I just followed this answer in my implementation, and could not see how `NotifyPropertyChanged`, which is a protected member of the `SalesPeriodV` class, could be in scope inside the setter of the `SelectedItem` property?

Comment: @dlatikay, that's a very valid point to raise. However, when writing WPF, it's fair to assume that each view model will implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (probably in a base class). Therefore, although the specific implementation of the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method from the `SalesPeriodV` class will *not* be accessible from the view model class, it will have its own implementation that it can call.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem where the *SelectedItem*-binding did not update when I selected something in the combobox. My problem was that I had to set *UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged* for the binding.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SalesPeriods}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: This one did it for me , Kudos

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- xaml code-->
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbData"    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedstudentInfo, Mode=OneWayToSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedIndex="0" />
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,150,0" Height="40" Width="70" Click="Button_Click">OK</Button>
    </Grid>



        //student Class
        public class Student
        {
            public  int Id { set; get; }
            public string name { set; get; }
        }

        //set 2 properties in MainWindow.xaml.cs Class
        public ObservableCollection<Student> studentInfo { set; get; }
        public Student SelectedstudentInfo { set; get; }

        //MainWindow.xaml.cs Constructor
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bindCombo();
            this.DataContext = this;
            cmbData.ItemsSource = studentInfo;

        }

        //method to bind cobobox or you can fetch data from database in MainWindow.xaml.cs
        public void bindCombo()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Student> studentList = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            studentList.Add(new Student { Id=0 ,name="==Select=="});
            studentList.Add(new Student { Id = 1, name = "zoyeb" });
            studentList.Add(new Student { Id = 2, name = "siddiq" });
            studentList.Add(new Student { Id = 3, name = "James" });

              studentInfo=studentList;

        }

        //button click to get selected student MainWindow.xaml.cs
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Student student = SelectedstudentInfo;
            if(student.Id ==0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("select name from dropdown");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Name :"+student.name + "Id :"+student.Id);
            }
        }
```