# How to do a Binding of a SelectValue to the MVVM in a project in UWP?

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, selectedvalue

I've been trying to capture the SelectValue of a comboBox in the ViewModel but I could not.

This is my code

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding TipoDoc, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

this is the ViewModel

```
private string tipodoc; 
public string TipoDoc 
{ 
    get => tipodoc; 
    set 
    { 
        tipodoc = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged();
     } 
}
```

I could not capture the value of the comboBox.

what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You should really read up on binding MVVM and `NotifyPropertyChanged` there are plenty of tutorials around, however this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632270/binding-combobox-selecteditem-using-mvvm

Comment: Did you set ItemsSource in ComboBox?..

Answer (score 0):

@Ashiq's suggestion was correct. You need to set ItemsSource for the ComboBox.

I made a code sample for your reference:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding source}" SelectedValue="{Binding TipoDoc, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string tipodoc;
    public string TipoDoc
    {
        get => tipodoc;
        set
        {
            tipodoc = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TipoDoc");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> source { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        source = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        source.Add("item1");
        source.Add("item2");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!= null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you select one item, the `TipoDoc` property value will be changed.
[image]