# WPF selected value in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

I'am struggling with ComboBox in my DataGrid View.

I have 2 Observable Collection. One for Data Grid where column DDV presents selected item of Combobox and second where are all options for CombBox.

Observable Collection DDV_Data (all ComboBox options) is in Observable Collection of ArtikliStoritveData.

My WPF looks like this:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ArtikliStoritveData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="True" x:Name="dgArtikliStoritve" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="229" Width="612">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Šifra" Binding="{Binding Sifra}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naziv" Binding="{Binding Naziv}" Width="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Znesek" Binding="{local:CultureAwareBinding Path=Znesek, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DDV" Binding="{local:CultureAwareBinding Path=DDV}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="EM" Binding="{Binding EM}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum spremembe" Binding="{local:CultureAwareBinding Path=DatumSpremembe}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DDV">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                            x:Name="cmbDDV"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DDV_Data}"
                            SelectedValuePath="DDV"
                            DisplayMemberPath="DDV"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding DDV1}"
                            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                            Width="50"
                        />
                        </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Artikel_ID}" Width="0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SkupinaArtikla}" Width="0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And my result in DataGrid is:

[image]

It is obvious that selected item is not working. What I'am doing wrong?

I am also wondering why ComboBox in new row doesn't get bind?

DDV_Data is part of Observable Collection which is binded to DataGrid:

```
                ArtikliStoritveData.Add(new ArtikliStoritve
                {    
                    Artikel_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["artikel_id"].ToString()),
                    SkupinaArtikla = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["skupina_artikla"].ToString()),
                    Sifra = dt.Rows[i]["sifra"].ToString(),
                    EM = dt.Rows[i]["em"].ToString(),
                    Naziv = dt.Rows[i]["naziv"].ToString(),
                    DDV = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["ddv"].ToString()),
                    DDV_Data = DDV_Data1,
                    SelectedItem = "22.0",
                    Znesek = Decimal.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["znesek"].ToString()) ,
                    DatumSpremembe = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["date_changed"].ToString())
                });
```

DDV Property in ArtikliStoritve model:

```
    public decimal DDV
    {
        get { return _ddv; }
        set { _ddv = value; }
```

I have also noticed that when I change value in ComboBox ith changes in every row???

ArtikliStoritve:

```
class ArtikliStoritve
{

    #region private varaibles
    int _artikel_id;
    int _skupinaArtikla;
    string _sifra;
    string _naziv;
    string _EM;
    decimal _ddv;
    decimal _znesek;
    DateTime _datum_spremembe;

    #endregion

    #region properties
    public int Artikel_ID
    {
        get { return _artikel_id; }
        set { _artikel_id = value; }
    }

    public int SkupinaArtikla
    {
        get { return _skupinaArtikla; }
        set { _skupinaArtikla = value; }
    }

    public string Sifra
    {
        get { return _sifra; }
        set { _sifra = value; }
    }

    public string EM
    {
        get { return _EM; }
        set { _EM = value; }
    }

    public string Naziv
    {
        get { return _naziv; }
        set { _naziv = value; }
    }

    public decimal DDV1
    {
        get { return _ddv; }
        set { _ddv = value; }
    }

    public decimal Znesek
    {
        get { return _znesek;}
        set { _znesek = value; }
    }

    public DateTime DatumSpremembe
    {
        get { return _datum_spremembe; }
        set { _datum_spremembe = value; }
    }

    private decimal _SelectedItem;
    public decimal SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set { _SelectedItem = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DDV_Class> _DDV_Data = new ObservableCollection<DDV_Class>();
    public ObservableCollection<DDV_Class> DDV_Data
    {
        get { return _DDV_Data; }
        set { _DDV_Data = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

For ComboBox I have a class:

```
class DDV_Class
{
    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }

    private decimal _DDV;
    public decimal DDV
    {
        get { return _DDV; }
        set { _DDV = value; }
    }
}
```

which i Fill in ArtikliStoritveViewModel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtDDV.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DDV_Data1.Add(new DDV_Class
    {
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(dtDDV.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()),
        DDV = Convert.ToDecimal(dtDDV.Rows[i]["DDV"].ToString())
    });
}
```

--> UPDATE

What I did. In ArtikliStoritve:

```
private DDV_Class _SelectedItem;
public DDV_Class SelectedItem
{
    get { return _SelectedItem; }
    set { _SelectedItem = value; }
}
```

When filling:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    ArtikliStoritveData.Add(new ArtikliStoritve
    {
        Artikel_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["artikel_id"].ToString()),
        SkupinaArtikla = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["skupina_artikla"].ToString()),
        Sifra = dt.Rows[i]["sifra"].ToString(),
        EM = dt.Rows[i]["em"].ToString(),
        Naziv = dt.Rows[i]["naziv"].ToString(),
        DDV1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["ddv"].ToString()),
        DDV_Data = DDV_Data1,
        SelectedItem = new DDV_Class { ID = 1, DDV = 22.0m },
        Znesek = Decimal.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["znesek"].ToString()),
        DatumSpremembe = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["date_changed"].ToString())
    });        
}
```

In ArtikliStoritveModelView I also have property:

```
public DDV_Class SelectedItem
{
    get { return ArtikliStoritve.SelectedItem; }
    set { ArtikliStoritve.SelectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
}
```

WPF look like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox
        x:Name="cmbDDV"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DDV_Data}"
        DisplayMemberPath="DDV"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        Width="50"
    />
</DataTemplate>
```

Result is same like picture above is showing.

--> UPDATE
I figure it out why value in all rows changed when I change value in comboBox in one row. Problem vas beacuse I added in each row one istance of Observable Collection:

DDV_Data1 is not instantiate for each row, so this is a problem - one object in all rows:

```
DataTable dtDDV = myDDV_DAL.getAll();
if (dtDDV.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtDDV.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DDV_Data1.Add(new DDV_Class
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dtDDV.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()),
            DDV = Convert.ToDecimal(dtDDV.Rows[i]["DDV"].ToString())
        });
    }
}

ArtikliStoritveDAL myArtikliStoritveDAL  = new ArtikliStoritveDAL();
DataTable dt = myArtikliStoritveDAL.getAll();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        ArtikliStoritveData.Add(new ArtikliStoritve
        {
            ...
            DDV_Data = DDV_Data1,
            ...
```

I did my testing on another column where this is now working:

```
EM_DAL myEM_DAL = new EM_DAL();
DataTable dtEM = myEM_DAL.getAll();
if (dtEM.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtEM.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        EM_Data.Add(new EM_Model
        {
            ID = dtEM.Rows[i]["EM"].ToString(),
            Naziv = dtEM.Rows[i]["EM"].ToString()
        });
    }
}

    ArtikliStoritveDAL myArtikliStoritveDAL  = new ArtikliStoritveDAL();
DataTable dt = myArtikliStoritveDAL.getAll();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        ArtikliStoritveData.Add(new ArtikliStoritve
        {
            ...
            EM_Data = getAll(dt.Rows[i]["em"].ToString()),
            ...


public List<EM_Model> getAll(string p_selected)
{
    List<EM_Model> myEM_Model = new List<EM_Model>();
    string strConnString = Util.getConnectionString();
    try
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT em, em "
                                                        + " FROM em", conn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            myEM_Model.Add(new EM_Model
            {
                ID = dt.Rows[i]["EM"].ToString(),
                Naziv = dt.Rows[i]["EM"].ToString(),
                SelectedItem1 = p_selected
            });
        }
        return myEM_Model;
```

Now I must figure it out why is value is not getting selected in comboBox. I tested with selected value created in object where all options for comboBox is (getAll()) or in collection ArtikliStoritveData. Neither one is working.

Keep searching for right solution... :)

If I serach contect in one row, Snoop showing me this(which is right):

[image]

If do this in WPF, selected value in Combobox is first value in list, not the correct one:

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="cmbEM"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EM_Data}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Naziv"
    SelectedItem="{Binding EM}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    Width="50"
/>
```

And finally I found a solution. Conjuction of SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath did the trick.

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="cmbDDV"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DDV_Data}"
    DisplayMemberPath="DDV"
    SelectedValue="{Binding DDV, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedValuePath="DDV" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    Width="50"
/>
```

On the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) I found additional informations which helped me.

Regards,
Igor

Comment: Looks like `DDV_Data` isn't a property of data items, which are bound to the grid rows. If you'll look at output window in Visual Studio, you'll see binding errors.

Comment: I don't have any error in Output window. I post a code which proves that DDV_Data is part of collection od ArtikliStoritveData.

Comment: Selected value in second row of DataGrid must be 22,0 like in first column DDV

Comment: Show your DVV property.  Show ArtikliStoritve

Comment: Show ArtikliStoritve and _ddv

Comment: Break it down with complete code to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can see where your error is... when data binding to a `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property, there are a few things to note. The first is that the object data bound to the `SelectedItem` property must be of the *same type as the items in the collection* that is data bound to the `ItemsSource` property.

From your code, it seems as though the collection you data bound to the `ItemsSource` property was of the type of a custom class... you didn't show that, but I guessed because you set the `DisplayMemberPath` to a value of `Naziv`. So either you'd need to make your `DDV` property that you data bind to the `SelectedItem` property the same type as the items in the collection , or you could try using the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` property in conjunction with the `SelectedValuePath` property instead:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbDDV" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DDV_Data}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Naziv"
    SelectedValuePath="Naziv"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DDV}"
    Width="50" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Your latest edit is *not* what I suggested. All the same, now that you've added the *relevant* code, I can see that `ArtikliStoritveData` is a collection of type `ArtikliStoritve` and `DDV_Data` is a property in that class which is a collection of type `DDV_Class`. Therefore, you need a property also of type `DDV_Class` in your `ArtikliStoritve` class that you can bind to the `SelectedIten` property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbDDV" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DDV_Data}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    Width="50" />

...

private DDV_Class _SelectedItem;
public DDV_Class SelectedItem
{
    get { return _SelectedItem; }
    set { _SelectedItem = value; }
}

private ObservableCollection<DDV_Class> _DDV_Data = new ObservableCollection<DDV_Class>();
public ObservableCollection<DDV_Class> DDV_Data
{
    get { return _DDV_Data; }
    set { _DDV_Data = value; }
}
```

Just a couple of things to note here for the future... if you want to set the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` from the code, the item that you set as the value *must be an actual item from the collection* that is bound to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property. You can do it like this:

```
SelectedItem = DDV_Data.Where(d => d.ID == someIdValue).Single();
```

Also, you should have got some errors displayed in the Output Window in Visual Studio... something like:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Some' property not found on 'object' ''NameOfDataBoundObject' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=SomePath; DataItem='NameOfDataBoundObject' (Name=''); target element is 'TypeOfUiElement' (Name='NameOfUiElement'); target property is 'PropertyName' (type 'TypeOfProperty')

These are all valuable clues... pay attention to them, because they help you track down your problems.

Comment: In output Window I get this:
ystem.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'Risa.Model.DDV_Class' (type 'DDV_Class'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem='ArtikliStoritve' (HashCode=34092959); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='cmbDDV'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: DecimalConverter cannot convert from Risa.Model.DDV_Class.

Comment: Did you drop SelectdItem like the posted answer?

Answer (score 0):

I added solution at the end of the question.

Regards,
Igor