# wpf combobox default selection from itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ComboBox in my WPF application where I display a list of items. Most of the times the first item is the correct choice in the itemssource list, only sometimes on a personal request the item could be changed. Now My combo box loads the list but never shows the first item at selected Item. Can anybody help me please. here's my code.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbxShipTo" TabIndex="0" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" ToolTip="Ship To is a Required Field" MinWidth="200" SelectedIndex="0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
IsEditable="False" DisplayMemberPath="ShipToCountyState" SelectedValuePath="ShipToValue">
<ComboBox.SelectedValue>
    <Binding Path="ShipToQAD" Mode="TwoWay">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <common:RequiredValidationRule ErrorMessage="Ship To is a Required Field" />
            <ExceptionValidationRule></ExceptionValidationRule>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</ComboBox.SelectedValue>
```

Code Behind:

```
cbxShipTo.ItemsSource = dbLookupService.GetShipToByCustomer(_inspectionListItems[0].CompanyID);
cbxShipTo.SelectedItem = cbxShipTo.Items.GetItemAt(0);
```

I have values in itemsSource, Selected itme hasa a value too, but never gets displayed on the screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath I personally would be careful mixing `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem`

Comment: Why are you setting `SelectedIndex` in one place but `SelectedItem` in another?  Also, you are setting values related to `SelectedValue` in your Xaml, but you are setting `SelectedItem` in your code behind.  Pick one selection mechanism and stick to it.  It's no surprise that you're running into problems when you're mixing all three.

Comment: I tried two different things but nothing works in my case. Even if I don't have SelectedItem, the combobox does not show up the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I ordinarily do this is by keeping a reference to the currently selected item in the ViewModel. (You should probably be doing this anyway, given that you shouldn't be querying the UI object itself to figure out the user's choice.) Initialize YourSelectedItem to the item you'd like to have appear as selected.

```
public List<YourType> YourItems { get; set; }
public YourType SelectedItem = YourItems[index];
```

Then bind SelectedItem to the YourItems property.

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem={Binding YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay} ... />
```

Anytime the user changes their selection in the ComboBox, the YourSelectedItem property will automatically be brought up to date.

You shouldn't need to use anything else other than SelectedItem.

Comment: Great it worked ....thanks for the quick response. Got rid of SelectedValue and used SelectedItem instead, now it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who still need this, You can just put `SelectedIndex` with the index to be shown on your combobox:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedIndex="0" ... />
```