# WPF ComboBox Set using Grid DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am new to `C# WPF`, I am tring to set `DataContext` to `combobox` my xml is a below

```
<Grid Name="groupEditArea"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFD8D8D8" Margin="-14,0,192,0">
                    <Label Content="Group Name" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136"/>
                    <Label Content="Group Type" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="groupGroupNameTxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Height="31" Margin="368,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path = GroupName, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:n3\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226"  TextChanged="groupGroupNameTxt_TextChanged"  /> <!-- GotFocus="GroupGroupNameTxt_OnGotFocus" TextInput="GroupGroupNameTxt_OnTextInput"  -->
                    <ComboBox x:Name="groupGroupNameCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="368,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226" Height="31" SelectionChanged="groupGroupNameCombo_SelectionChanged"  DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" SelectedValuePath="CategoriesVal" SelectedValue="{Binding Categories}"/>
                </Grid>
```

my `POCO` as below :-

```
        public class Test: INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public Test()
            {
            }
     public virtual string TestId { get; set; }
            public virtual Categories CategoriesVal { get; set; }
     public virtual string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual string GroupName
            {
                get { return Name; }
                set
                {
                    Name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
                }
            }
    }

public class Categories : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public Categories ()
            {
            }
 public virtual string CategorieId { get; set; }
     public virtual string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual string GroupName
            {
                get { return Name; }
                set
                {
                    Name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and in my `backend` code i am setting `DataContext` as below :-

```
Categories cate = new Categories ();
cate.CategorieId = "cate1ID";
cate.GroupName = "CateGroupName1"
Test test = new Test();
test.TestId = "TestID";
test.CategoriesVal  = cate;
test.Name = "TestName1";
```

and `groupGroupNameCombo` is set using `ItemsSource` and that contain entire list on `Categories` when i set using below its working fine

```
groupGroupNameCombo.SelectedItem = cate;
```

but when i set using below to grid it wont work :-

```
groupEditArea.DataContext = test;
```

can someone guide me how can i set `combobox` by setting grid `DataContext` instead of setting manually `combobox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead

```
SelectedValuePath="CategoriesVal" SelectedValue="{Binding Categories}"
```

write

```
SelectedItem="{Binding CategoriesVal}"
```

`SelectedValuePath` means: the name of property (from the ComboBoxItem DataContex - `Categories` class In our case) from which the value of `SelectedValue` will be provided.
 This is useful in case you want to representation of a instance-item (each form `Combobox.Items`) is not done by the item itself, but by one characteristic. In your case I do not see any point in it.

see more: [Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4902039/1271037)