# Combobox selected item doesn't show up On Load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `ListView` with an `ComboBox` in its `ItemTemplate`.  The `ComboBox` is also bound to the same list as of the `ListView` with a Converter. The `ComboBox` is populated properly but the `SelectedItem` doesn't show up.

I have tried overriding the `Equals` method of the underlying object too.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="FactorsListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding FactorList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFactor, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid d:DesignWidth="461.333" d:DesignHeight="368.96">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Height="30.96" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Monetary, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                        <Label Content="Related Quantitative Factor:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <ComboBox Margin="171.707,4,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FactorList, ElementName=UcGrid, Converter={StaticResource QtyFacConverter}}" SelectedItem="{Binding RelatedQuantityFactor}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView>
```

Converter:

```
public class FactorConverters : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Factor> givenList = value as ObservableCollection<Factor>;
        ObservableCollection<Factor> rList = new ObservableCollection<Factor>();
        if (givenList != null)
        {
            foreach(Factor factor in givenList)
            {
                if (!factor.IsMonetary)
                {
                    rList.Add(factor);
                }
            }
        }
        return rList;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Factor Class:

```
public class Factor : ModelBase
{
    private Factor _RelatedQuantityFactor;

    public Factor RelatedQuantityFactor
    {
        get
        {
            return _RelatedQuantityFactor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_RelatedQuantityFactor != value)
            {
                _RelatedQuantityFactor = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("RelatedQuantityFactor");
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Factor))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            bool res = ((Factor)obj).ID == this.ID;
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

FactorsViewModel class:

```
public class FactorsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Factor> _FactorList;
    private RevenueItem _SelectedRevenueItem;
    private ObservableCollection<Factor> _UniversalFactors;
    private Factor _SelectedFactor;
    private ObservableCollection<Factor> _QuantitativeFactorHelperList;

    public ObservableCollection<Factor> FactorList
    {
        get
        {
            return _FactorList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_FactorList != value)
            {
                _FactorList = value;
                AttachFactorListner(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AttachFactorListner(ObservableCollection<Factor> value)
    {
        foreach (Factor factor in value)
        {
            factor.PropertyChanged += factor_PropertyChanged;
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged("FactorList");
    }

    void factor_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsMonetary")
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("FactorList");
        }
    }


    public RevenueItem SelectedRevenueItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedRevenueItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedRevenueItem != value)
            {
                _SelectedRevenueItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRevenueItem");
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Factor> UniversalFactors
    {
        get
        {
            return _UniversalFactors;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_UniversalFactors != value)
            {
                _UniversalFactors = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UniversalFactors");
            }
        }
    }
    public Factor SelectedFactor
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedFactor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedFactor != value)
            {
                _SelectedFactor = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFactor");
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Factor> QuantitativeFactorHelperList
    {
        get
        {
            return _QuantitativeFactorHelperList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_QuantitativeFactorHelperList != value)
            {
                _QuantitativeFactorHelperList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("QuantitativeFactorHelperList");
            }
        }
    }

    public FactorsViewModel(RevenueItem revenueItem)
    {
        _SelectedRevenueItem = revenueItem;
        _FactorList = revenueItem.Factors;
        AttachFactorListner(_FactorList);

    }


}
```

The View and Viewmodels: [PostImg Link](http://postimg.org/image/hiwb2y8w7/)

Comment: Where is the "FactorList" property ?

Comment: It is on the viewmodel of Usercontrol which hosts the listview

Comment: public class FactorsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Factor> _FactorList;

        public ObservableCollection<Factor> FactorList
        {
            get
            {
                return _FactorList;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_FactorList != value)
                {
                    _FactorList = value;
                    AttachFactorListner(value);
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `SelectedItem` to Some `Property` in the `ViewModel`

As I saw in your code you bound it to the Property `RelatedQuantityFactor` from your model `Factor` not from `ViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

Let's see **MVVM** pattern.
[image]

**ViewModel** should inherit from `InotifyPropertyChanged` so that it can update **View**.
 **Model** is **Object** which include **Property** and **Behavior**,but it doesn't communicate with **View**

So,if you wang to update your **UI** ,you should use **Data Binding**.
I think `Factor` is **ViewModel**.

```
public class Factor: ModelBase
{
    private ItemViewModel _selectedFactor;
    Public ItemViewModel SelectedFactor
     {
        get
        {
           return _selectedFactor;
        }
        set
        {
         _selectedFactor = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("RelatedQuantityFactor");
        }
     }
}
```

you also should change the **Binding Mode**.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFactor, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Finally, don't forget to assign **DataContext**

```
FactorsListView.DataContext = new Factor();
```

Comment: Factor is a model and not a viewmodel. Added a pic in the question to clarify.

Comment: @eskawl ModelBase inherit from interface Inotifypropertychanged?

Comment: Yes. It inherits and raises the property changed events.

Comment: @eskawl if Factor  is model, it shouldn't inherit from interface Inotifypropertychanged.

Comment: then what should it do to raise property changed notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Just some question:

1. Do the viewmodel contain any variable name "RelatedQuantityFactor"?

Try to post your code behind which include d initialization of data context and viewmodel if you still face any problem .

Update :
You can try to put breakpoint into your setter and getter of RelatedQuantityFactor to investigate whether it update your relatedquantityfactor as you expected

Update 2:
See this [Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath).

Hope its helps  :)

Comment: 1. No the viewmodel doesn't contain any variable named RelatedQuantityFactor.  2. Yes the selected item is on the factor class.  If this is wrong,  How should i implement the relation between factor and its relative factor by storing the relative factor in the viewmodel?

Comment: @eskawl ooaps sorry i mistaken the relationship, please wait awhile i am updating my answer.

Comment: The binding doesn't point to viewmodel.  even if it had, i'd have got an binding error not found in the output during runtime, but there isn't any.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the selected item doesn't appear on load. Changing the binding mode of the parent listview had no effect.

Comment: @eskawl selectedItem doesn't appear on load... does it means the default select value doesn't appear?

Comment: not the default but the actual related factor doesn't appera

Comment: @eskawl have you tried put a breakpoint in the set and get of relatedQuantityFactor? does it enter the set and get when you select a value?

Comment: Yes it enters the get

Comment: I read somewhere that the selectedItem is getting set before the items are populated.  So how should I deal with this.