# WPF - How to get selected value binded to a table model

Tags: wpf, data-binding, linq-to-sql, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a combo box category that is binded to an `ObservableCollection Categories` based on `tbl_Category` with two properties `CategoryName` and `CategoryDescription`. Now I want to add the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` to product table property `Prod_Category`

In my constructor :

```
cb.DataContext = Categories;
this.DataContext = new tbl_Product();
```

Combo box xaml :

```
<Combobox x:Name="cb" ItemSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedValuePath="CategoryName" SelectedValue="{Binding Prod_Category,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In my save product event :

```
tbl_Product prod = (tbl_Product)this.DataContext;
DataOperations.AddProduct(prod);
```

I get `Prod_Category` to `null` even after doing all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use SelectedItem  instead of SelectedValue, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath).

besides that what you are willing to do wasn't so clear, I've tried to implement what you asked for based on my understanding

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Category> _categories;
    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            return _categories;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_categories == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _categories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private Category _prod_Category ;
    public Category Prod_Category
    {
        get
        {
            return _prod_Category;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_prod_Category == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _prod_Category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Categories=new ObservableCollection<Category>()
        {
            new Category()
            {
                CategoryName = "Name1",
                CategoryDescription = "Desc1"
            },new Category()
            {
                CategoryName = "Name2",
                CategoryDescription = "Desc2"
            }
        };
    }

    public void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        if (Prod_Category!=null)
        {
            //add it to whatever you want

        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategoryDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and the xaml

```
 <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedValuePath="CategoryName" SelectedItem="{Binding Prod_Category,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Click="SaveButton_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

you should consider implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to notify the UI if any changes occurs in one of the binded properties

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @samthedev 's provided answer, I would also recommend you change your assignment of `DataContext` from:

```
tbl_Product prod = (tbl_Product)this.DataContext;
DataOperations.AddProduct(prod);
```

to

```
tbl_Product prod = this.DataContext as tbl_Product;
if (tbl_Product != null)
{
    DataOperations.AddProduct(prod);
}
```

This prevents any change of DataContext being accidentally bound to a different object and causing an unhandled exception due to the fact that DataContext does have tbl_Product as its base-type which can happen more often than you realise in WPF due to DataContext inheritance when someone changes something at a higher level.