# combobox showing System.Data.DataRowView in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

xaml code:

```
 xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
     <xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="Cb_Blowshell" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,9,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267"  DisplayMemberPath="prod_name"  ValueMemberPath="Id"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

c# code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("blow_shell");
String Qry = "select Id,prod_name from blow_shell where weight=" + Txt.Text.Trim().ToString() + "";
SqlHelper.Fill_dt(dt, Qry);
Cb_Blowshell.ItemsSource= dt.DefaultView;
```

Its brief code to bind datatable data to combobox; but my resulted display member show `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind the data using this line of code:

```
Cb_Blowshell.ItemsSource= dt.DefaultView;
```

I guess you want to display the `prod_name` column of your database table as the content of each item in the `CheckComboBox`.

Try this (insert it after the "Fill_dt" method call):

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    String prodName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["prod_name"]);
    names.Add(prodName );
}

Cb_Blowshell.ItemsSource = names;
```

By the way:
Your output "`System.Data.DataRowView`" is a typical example of when you try to bind to a source type in this case `DataRowView` which does not fit to the target control (in your case: an item of the `CheckComboBox`).
In this case you will see the output of the `ToString` method of the bound source object. So here you see the output of the "ToString" method of the `Object` base class which does this: `this.GetType().ToString();`.

Comment: Hey try with  this method,works fine but i want both display member and value member.

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? There is only "Id" and "prod_name" in your select statement. You could create a class for these two fields, create a list of those objects and bind them as items source. In this case you have to set the `DisplayMemberPath`. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454/4424024