# WPF combobox binding and SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a list containing instances of the following class:

```
namespace Foo.InformationModel.Reference
{
    public class ReferenceCodeTypeChar
    {
        public ReferenceCodeTypeChar();

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string CodeValue { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the object that is used as the `DataContext` for the window in which the combobox is and its related properties:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<Foo.InformationModel.Reference.ReferenceCodeTypeChar> ProgramTypes() {...}

    private string _selectedProgramTypeCode;
    public string SelectedProgramTypeCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedProgramTypeCode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedProgramTypeCode != value)
            {
                _selectedProgramTypeCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProgramTypeCode");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml code behind for the combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProgramTypes}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProgramTypeCode, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description"
          SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
```

The problem happens inside SelectedProgramTypeCode. The value of the "value" variable is Foo.InformationModel.Reference.ReferenceCodeTypeChar instead of the expected string of Value property of the ReferenceCodeTypeChar object. What is wrong?

Comment: @Hopeless You should write this as an answer, because it is true.

Comment: well I was wrong with a quick glance at the XAML. Looks like the `SelectedItem` is bound wrong. It should be bound to a property of type `Foo.InformationModel.Reference.ReferenceCodeTypeChar`, in this case you bind it to a string property. In the way from `SelectedItem` to `SelectedProgramTypeCode`, there is no Converter, so `ToString()` will be called on `SelectedItem` and resolved to `"Foo.InformationModel.Reference.ReferenceCodeTypeChar"` before being set to `SelectedProgramTypeCode` (so you see it in `value` variable).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `SelectedItem` **or** `SelectedValuePath` in conjunction with `SelectedValue`.

See this answer [Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` in your XAML.

```
<ComboBox 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProgramTypes}"
  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedProgramTypeCode, Mode=TwoWay}"
  DisplayMemberPath="Description"
  SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```