# ComboBox binding to referenced (relative) source

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

When binding `ComboBox` to referenced source:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Source.SelectedItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source.Items}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

where `Source` is

```
SourceType _source;
public SourceType Source
{
    get { return _source; }
    set { _source = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

and `SourceType` is

```
public class SourceType: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Item _selectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { _selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Item> Items { get; }

    public SourceType(...)
    {
        Items = new List<Items>(...) // **new** list generated from passed arguments
        SelectedItem = Items.First();
    }
}
```

and `Item` is

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

following happens:

- for only one source (if `Source` never changes) it works: `ComboBox` display list of `Items` and correct item is selected (I can see its `Name` when switching view);
- for more than one items `ComboBox` bugs: has no selection (but drop-down list is there and working fine), selection doesn't persist when switching view or `Source` is changed (e.g. between 2 sources).

It seems like `ComboBox` has some problems to identify `SelectedValue` or find it in the `ItemsSource`. And I can't figure out what is wrong.

Debugging does not uncover anything: `Items` is set correctly, `SelectedItem` is **first** item from `Items` collection, yet `ComboBox` is displayed without selection. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use a ObservableCollection instead of a List for Items and use SelectedItem for the ComboBox, not SelectedValue.

Read this great answer for differences between SelectedItem and SelectedValue
[Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Comment: `ObservableCollection` won't help (list is not changed ever, no need for notification). But `SelectedItem` did the trick, thanks. Didn't noticed I am using wrong property to bind.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the asnwer if it helped you. Good Work.

Answer (score 0):

@Giangregorio answer is good and working in general, but now I remember why I used `SelectedValue` in first place.

`SelectedValue` is useful whenever `ItemsSource` **does not** contains `SelectedValue`. If `SelectedItem` is used (as per answer), then binding will call setter with `null` as if the user could select `null` from the list. I am exploiting this case (to avoid having data-templates and more complicated ViewModel), so I have to stick with `SelectedValue` and I think I found the reason of the problem in otherwise *should-work* case.

I have to declare `ItemsSource` binding first and `SelectedValue` second:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source.Items}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding Source.SelectedItem}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

It works!

Sounds to me like another xaml-specific issue, similar to `declare CommandParameter before Command` problem.

Comment: Using SelectedValue without using SelectedValuePath shouldn't be different from using SelectedItem...however if it works , It works!

Comment: @Giangregorio, yes, but it required exactly that order to work properly. Setting `ItemsSource` before setting `SelectedValue`. If `SelectedItem` is used then order doesn't matter. Which is ... interesting?