# Getting content value from combo box on C#

Tags: c#, uwp

can we retrieve the content from combobox without data binding? This is my xaml code

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Choice" Header="Choice your eating time" PlaceholderText="Pilih" Width="200" SelectionChanged="Choice_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Breakfast" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Lunch" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Dinner"/>
 </ComboBox>
```

I tried with `choice.SelectedItem.ToString()` but the result will be Windows.UI.XAML.ComboBox, not the content of combobox. I want to pass it into listbox and when I used `choice.SelectedValue.ToString()` it contain same result with SelectedItem.

Comment: try the `SelectedValue` property

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I understand the differences between SelectedItems, SelectedIndex, and SelectedValue, I tried to pass it to listbox and it shows Windows.UI.Xaml.ComboBox (I'm forgot the result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Olivia Olga Clarissa try this ..

```
Text = ((ComboBoxItem)Choice.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();

or

var comboBoxItem = Choice.Items[Choice.SelectedIndex] as ComboBoxItem;
if (comboBoxItem != null)
{
    string selectedcmb = comboBoxItem.Content.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried the first one and it's working now. I used for passes to listbox.

Answer (score 1):

use choice.SelectedItem.Content, in case you are not seeing the property, cast it to ((ContentControl)choice.SelectedItem).Content