# How to bind combobox display string and value string through list wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Need to bind a combobox through list in wpf binding its display string and value string . I am only able to bind the display text , how to to bind value text in pair with display text ?

```
List<string> value = new List<string>();
value.Add("a");
value.Add("b");
route_select_points.ItemsSource = value;
```

**The value text stays hidden in frontend**

Here is the example of sample data (updated detailed)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEQmQ.png

Comment: What is the Display text and value text?

Comment: could you please post your XAML

Comment: The properties you need to set in your xaml are `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath`, [ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454/6741868)

Comment: @DenisKosov Kosov please see the image provided for example data

Comment: @FawadTariq see answer

Comment: are you talking about `ListView` or `ComboBox` ?

Comment: @DarshanPatel ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use ListView with GridView, see next:

```
<ListView Name="route_select_points" Margin="5">
          <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ValueText}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Display" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayText}"></GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
     </ListView>
```

And for binding you need to define your class with properties: "ValueText", "DisplayText", as example I suggest

```
public class SomeData
{
    public string ValueText { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

And the creating of list will be:

```
var value = new List<SomeData>();
value.Add(new SomeData(){ ValueText = "1", DisplayText = "a"});
value.Add(new SomeData(){ ValueText = "2", DisplayText = "b"});
route_select_points.ItemsSource = value;
```

Comment: Your answer is fine for listview but I need to bind it to combobox . Please see the latest update of example image , I actually need to bind the BackEndData to combobox , on selection of combobox the value is mapped with display text