# WPF Custom Controls - Multiple ways to Bind a Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a WPF custom combo box that is for selecting Contacts.  I'd like to expose multiple ways of interfacing with the combo box's selected item and I'd like them to be bindable.

```
public class ContactComboBox : ComboBox {
    public ContactJson SelectedContact {get; set;}
    public long? SelectedContactId {get; set; }
}
```

I know how to handle single properties that bind to single values with dependency properties, but how do I have a change in one property affect the change in another?

For example:

```
<local:ContactComboBox SelectedContactId="{Binding ContactId}" />
```

When the ContactID on the datasource is changed, both the SelectedContact and SelectedContactId values should be changed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Comment: Create two dependency properties. In the PropertyChangedCallback of one property just update the other and vice versa.