# ComboBox SelectedValue not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(18, 38).Cast<object>().ToArray());
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
Console.WriteLine(comboBox.SelectedValue + "test");
```

I get just "test" without the "18" printed. I also don't clearly understand what's the difference between SelectedValue and SelectedItem, even if I read the guide.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) not help? `SelectedValue` relies on `SelectedValuePath`. It seems you want `SelectedItem` here.

Comment: The WPF combobox's Items collection doesn't have an AddRange() method. Is this really winforms, not WPF? In winforms, `ComboBox.Items` has an `AddRange(object[] items)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're populating your combo box with integers, which have no value property. They *are* the value. So what you want is SelectedItem, which gives you the whole object the user selected.