# WPF combobox binding with external source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am having a problem with databinding on a `ComboBox`. The combobox does not show initially set items.

My .xaml:

```
<ComboBox 
    Name="LeaderTextBox" 
    Grid.Column="6" 
    Grid.Row="2"  
    MinWidth="150" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProjectLeader}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5" 
    />
```

In the code I set the `ItemSource` like this:

```
LeaderTextBox.ItemsSource = service.GetAllEmployee();
```

`service.GetAllEmployee()` returns a list/array of employees and they are also filled into the combobox, meaning I can select them.

My problem is that if I have a value set for `ProjectLeader`, then it is not displayed. What am I missing there?

---

Model for reference:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared", IsReference = true)]
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Projects = new List<Project>();
    } 

    [DataMember]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String JobDescription { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Department { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String DirectDialing { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Project LeaderOfProject { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID + " " + Name + " " + JobDescription + " " + Department + " " + DirectDialing;
    }


}
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared", IsReference = true)]
public class Project
{

    public Project()
    {
        this.EmployeesWorkingOnProject = new List<Employee>();
        this.ProjectSteps = new List<ProjectStep>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Titel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Employee ProjectLeader { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Employee> EmployeesWorkingOnProject { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<ProjectStep> ProjectSteps { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID +" "+ Titel+" "+StartDate+ " "+ EndDate +" "+ Description;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `ProjectLeader`? For `SelectedItem` to work here, it should be the name of a property on your DataContext object, the value of which should be an object of type `Employee`, which **must be** contained in the collection of objects returned by `service.GetAllEmployee()`. Not just "has the same ID", but the actual instance has to be in there. The way you're populating the listbox that seems unlikely.

Comment: I'd advise making the employee collection a property of the viewmodel, then the viewmodel can scan through the collection for Rodolfo Dopamine or whoever, and assign his actual instance of `Employee` to `ProjectLeader`. Or else go by `SelectedValue`/`SelectedValuePath="ID"`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean with `SelectedValue/SelectedValuePath="ID"`. I tried `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ProjectLeader.ID}" SelectedValuePath="ID"` and `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ProjectLeader}" SelectedValuePath="ID"`, but no success. Could you give me an example on how to solve it?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on ComboBox.SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) (Selector is a common base class for ComboBox, ListBox, etc.)? [This may help as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454/424129). You have to understand what it means.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I read everything and I understand the problem (the value I want to display is not the same as in the list I set as `ItemSource`), but I still have no idea on how to fix it

Comment: What Employee object do you want to select initially?

Comment: @mm8 either nothing if the `Project.ProjectLeader` is null, or the proper `Project.ProjectLeader` if one is set

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Where and how do you instantiate the Project class?

Comment: @mm8 its always fetched from database in that case. I also have a case where I create a `new Project()` but there is no need to set the `ProjectLeader`

Comment: You bind to a ProjectLeader property in your XAML...where is this property defined and set?

Comment: @mm8 defined in `Project` class. Mapping is done through EF (working just fine for select)

Comment: Then again, where is this instance of Project defined? Post your code if you want any help. Where do you set the value to be selected in the ComboBox?

Comment: `Where do you set the value to be selected in the ComboBox` -> read the question. But why does it even matter? It is clearly stated what I want to achieve (1 POCO and a list of other POCOs as `ItemSource`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't select an item of a combo box by an item which is not in the combo box.

Right:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var paul = new Employee { Name = "Paul" };
        LeaderTextBox.ItemsSource = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee {Name = "Bob" },
            paul,
            new Employee {Name = "Alex" },
        };
        ProjectLeader = paul;
    }
```

Wrong:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LeaderTextBox.ItemsSource = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee {Name = "Bob" },
            new Employee { Name = "Paul" },
            new Employee {Name = "Alex" },
        };
        ProjectLeader = new Employee {Name = "Paul" };
    }
```

Comment: I already understood that issue. Right now I am looking for a way to make it automagically

Comment: then you need to select the project leader "from" the list assigned to the items source.