# C# WPF - Databinding DataGridComboboxColumn SelectedValueBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I´m trying to bind Data to a DataGridComboBoxColumn.

I already managed to bind the ItemsSource, but the bound value won´t be selected, instead the ComboBox has just nothing selected.

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Name" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static K:Material.loadedMaterials}}" DisplayMemberPath="name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name2" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Material-Class:

```
public class Material {
    public static List<Material> loadedMaterials;

    static Material() {
        loadedMaterials = new List<Material>();

        loadedMaterials.Add(new Material("TEST1", "", ""));
        loadedMaterials.Add(new Material("TEST2", "", ""));
        loadedMaterials.Add(new Material("TEST3", "", ""));
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name2 { get; set; }
    public string name3 { get; set; }

    public Material(string n, string n2, string n3) {
        name = n;
        name2 = n2;
        name3 = n3;
    }
}
```

Main Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Material> mat;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        mat = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Material>();
        mat.Add(new Material("TEST1", "TEST1", "TEST1"));

        dg.DataContext = mat;
    }
}
```

As you can see here, the DropDown is loaded and the Textbox, which has the same data bound, shows it correctly, but the ComboBox is empty.

I´m excpecting `TEST1` to be selected and displayed in the ComboBox.

[image]

Comment: With nothing selected you mean that you don't see the value in the combobox, right?

Comment: @FredM Yes excactly. Since the Bound List has one Object in it, I excpect that value (TEST1) to show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `SelectedValuePath` on your `DataGridComboBoxColumn`

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Name" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static K:Material.loadedMaterials}}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="name"/>
```

Comment: Thats working, thanks. Can you explain whats the difference between those two properties? I just started working with Databindings and thought `SelectedValueBinding` should do the whole trick.

Comment: @TimSchmidt `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue(Binding)` are always used together as an alternative to `SelectedItem`. `SelectedValuePath` is the path to the property of the `SelectedItem` that is returned by the `SelectedValue`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thak you for the explanation. :)