# How to change the editable ComboBox's text to something else when a specific ComboBoxItem is selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, selectionchanged

The new text will never be present in the items inside `ComboBox`. Below is the full XAML + code-behind that does not work as I wish. What I am trying to achieve is to have the user select an actual group of items from the combo box, or a *`No Group`* (italic, grayed out) item that should be applied as an empty string in the text box inside the `ComboBox`.

I also tried:

1. with `StaysOpenOnEdit="True"` (with the same result) and
2. by handling the `Selected` event of the `"click me"` `ComboBoxItem` (the event handler is called before the `Text` or `SelectedItem` properties of the ComboBox change).

## XAML

```
<Window x:Class="cs_wpf_test_12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cs_wpf_test_12"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                  IsEditable="True">
            <ComboBoxItem>test</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Gray">click me</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

## Code-behind

```
internal bool HandlingSelectionChange = false;
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (HandlingSelectionChange)
    {
        return;
    }
    HandlingSelectionChange = true;
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb.Text == "click me")
    {
        cb.Text = "";
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    HandlingSelectionChange = false;
}
```

*Expected:* when the user clicks on the "click me" item in the drop-down the text of the `ComboBox` becomes an empty string. The rest of the items, when clicked, should copy their text normally into the text box of the `ComboBox`.

*Actual:*

1. Start the program.
2. Select the "click me" item.
3. The Text changes to "click me" (not grayed out) instead of "".
4. Click on the "test" item.
5. The Text changes to "" (empty string) instead of "test".
6. Click again on the "test" item.
7. The Text changes to "test".

## Update

I wish to use MVVM but I am still a beginner. I have several `ComboBox`es like shown above inside a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, and for each of the `ComboBox`es (which should have the same drop-down contents) I think I should have a ViewModel for each of its `ComboBoxItem`s. If possible, I would like to learn how I could I use MVVM correctly in this situation.

### The big XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding GroupName, Mode=OneWay}">
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Clocks.GroupsVM,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ClockDataGrid}}"
                        PreviewKeyDown="ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown"
                        SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                        Text="{Binding GroupName}">
                <ComboBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="{Binding FontStyle}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Resources>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

### The big code-behind

```
private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;

    if ((e.Key == Key.Return ||
        e.Key == Key.Enter) &&
        cb.Text != "")
    {
        bool duplicate = false;
        foreach (ClockGroupVM vm in Clocks.GroupsVM)
        {
            if (vm.Name == cb.Text)
            {
                cb.SelectedItem = vm;
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (duplicate)
        {
            return;
        }

        // create a ClockGroupM and corresponding ClockGroupVM
        // (ClockGroupVM inherits from ClockGroupM)
        var cvm = new ClockGroupVM()
        {
            Name = cb.Text
        };
        Clocks.Groups.Insert(0, cvm);
        cb.SelectedItem = cvm;
    }
}

internal bool HandlingSelectionChange = false;
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (HandlingSelectionChange)
    {
        return;
    }
    HandlingSelectionChange = true;

    var cb = sender as ComboBox;

    //if (cb.SelectedItem is the VM with Style != Normal)

    ClockGroupVM foundVM = null;
    foreach (ClockGroupVM vm in Clocks.GroupsVM)
    {
        if (vm.FontStyle != FontStyles.Normal &&
            ReferenceEquals(cb.SelectedItem, vm))
        {
            foundVM = vm;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundVM != null)
    {
        cb.Text = "";
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    HandlingSelectionChange = false;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to use WPF the old way which it was never designed for. Thats how you would work with winforms. I highly recommend using MVVM and Databindings for future as this will solve isssues like this in a way more elegant way and also is the designpattern WPF was designed around. If you however instist on doing it like this use your debugger and see what cb.Text is and you will see it is not "click me" yet when you check for it

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox.Text wont update immediately in the SelectionChanged event. You can use SelectedValue's content instead. And set SelectedValue to null. Change your if condition like this.

```
if ((cb.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "click me")
{
    cb.Text = "";
    cb.SelectedValue = null;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for which I must set SelectedValue to null? Is it OK if in the condition I use SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue?

Comment: Learn about SelectedValue and SelectedItem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath

Comment: @silviubogan You can set it as Answer it it resolves your issue. So that it will help others who face same issue.