# Setting the initial selection or default value of a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to set the initial selected value (or default value) of a combo box.  When the user selects an incident record, the incident status from the incident record is supposed to show up as the default selection of the combo box, instead of the blank selection that appears at the top of the combo box list.  I've tried:

1. Two-way binding the combo box selected value to a property in my model and then setting the property as the incident data is loaded,
2. Two-way binding the combo box selected index to a property in my model and then setting the property as the incident data is loaded,
3. Two-way binding the both the combo box selected index and value to a properties in my model and then setting the properties as the incident data is loaded,

but no matter what I tried, the combo box still shows as it would initially with the blank line for a default showing on top of the list.

Here is the XAML for the ComboBox:

```
    <ComboBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
    IsEnabled="{qc:Binding '!$P', P={Binding Path=Form104CModel.IsPartINA}}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
    SelectedValuePath="Code" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Form104CModel.IncidentStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Margin="2,0,2,0" Name="cmbxIncidentStatus" 
    FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Width="180">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <domain:Enumeration Code="" Description="" />
            <CollectionContainer 
                 Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static infraData:CodeCache.ClearedException}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Here are the properties in the model to which the selected index and selected value are bound:

```
  private int incidentStatusSelectedIndex;
    public int IncidentStatusSelectedIndex
   {
        get
        {
            return this.incidentStatusSelectedIndex;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.incidentStatusSelectedIndex != value)
            {
                this.incidentStatusSelectedIndex = value;
            }
        }
    }

   private string incidentStatus;
    [CustomValidation(typeof(Form104CModel), "ValidateIncidentStatus")]
    public string IncidentStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.incidentStatus;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.incidentStatus != value)
            {
                this.ValidateProperty("IncidentStatus", value);
                this.incidentStatus = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IncidentStatus");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the code (from the ViewModel) that sets the value of the incident status.

```
              switch (rr.Incident.IncidentStatus)
                {
                    case "A":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "CLEARED BY ARREST";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 1;
                        break;
                    case "D":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "DEATH OF OFFENDER";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 2;
                        break;
                    case "E":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "EXTRADITION DECLINED";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 3;
                        break;
                    case "J":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "JUVENILE, NO CUSTODY";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 4;
                        break;
                    case "O":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "OPEN";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 5;
                        break;
                    case "P":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "PROSECUTION DECLINED";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 6;
                        break;
                    case "R":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "REFUSED TO COOPERATE";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 7;
                        break;
                    case "U":
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatus = "UNFOUNDED";
                        this.Form104CModel.IncidentStatusSelectedIndex = 8;
                        break;
                }
```

The only thing that I can think of now is that the ComboxBox.ItemsSource is somehow thwarting my efforts to select a default based on the incident status field.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't try and bind two properties; just use the selected value. Is the selected value certainly in the items collection and is the combo correctly referencing that particular property within the item of the bound collection? I don't do much WPF; if this were win forms I'd need to do 4 things: Set the DataSource(items list),set DisplayMember(property to render in box),set ValueMember(property to use as SelectedValue), bind SelectedValue to the property in the object that the combo has to edit. If WPF is similar you're maybe missing a ValueMemberPath and should unbind SelectedIndex?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but more a series of thoughts too big to fit in comments:

- Binding both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` often leads to problems. `SelectedItem` is the easier one to deal with, bind it to an observable property on the VM and the combo will react when you set it, assuming you're setting it to an object that exists in the `ItemsSource` collection. `SelectedValue` normally needs to be used with `SelectedValuePath` and is used for deconstructing more complex objects. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) gives a good overview of the difference.
- Which brings me to the `ItemsSource`. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with the `CompositeCollection` but it doesn't look like it contains anything that would be applicable to the `SelectedItem`.

At it's most basic, combo box binding is as simple as

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding VMItemsSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding VMSelectedItem}"/>
```

Where `VMItemsSource` is a Collection of `<Something>` and `VMSelectedItem` is an observable property of the same type:

```
public ObservableCollection<Something> VMItemsSource {get; set;}

public Something VMSelectedItem
{
  get 
  {
    return this.vmSelectedItem;
  }
  set
  {
    this.vmSelectedItem = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.VMSelectedItem));
  }
}
```

Then, after the `ItemsSource` collection is built you just need this to initalise it:

```
this.VMSelectedItem = this.VMItemsSource.First();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, MarcE.  I think you helped me trip over the answer.  I changed the ComboBox SelectedValue to 'SelectedValue="{Binding Form104CModel.Incident.IncidentStatus, Mode=TwoWay}", which the status field in the Incident object.  I think it worked because the status field in the incident object is a code.  The ComboBox selected path is also a code.  I was trying to equate a code to a description.  I should have been matching code-to-code.