# SelectedItem not working in a wpf combobox after the itemtemplate has been modified

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, selecteditem, itemtemplate

I have a combobox and I have bound it to a dictionary.

The dictionary is defined as:

```
        Cities = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"USA", "NewYork"},
            {"UK", "London"},
            {"Canada", "Toronto"}
        };
```

The combobox is bound to the dictionary as follows:

```
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CitiesComboBox" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}" Margin="10" Background="Transparent">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}  {0}'}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
```

The binding works fine but I am having trouble setting the selecteditem of the combobox to "London".

Since the itemtemplate is not a single string property, the combobox selecteditem property is not binding to string value "London"

Thanks,
Sath

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `SelectedValuePath` property to "Value". Then when you set `SelectedValue` to "London", ComboBox will map its selection to the item that has "London" set to its `Value` property, which will solve your problem
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) is a post that goes in deeper details on the different usage of the selection properties.