# How do I handle SelectionChange when the ComboBox is

Tags: c#, xaml, events, selectionchanged

I have a ListBox, where the list element has a ComboBox, a TextBox and a slider. Depending on the selction of the ComboBox either the TextBox or the slider should be visible.

```
    <ListBox Name="lstPWM" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <!-- more definitions -->
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Gebertyp, Converter={local1:EnumToCollectionConverter}, Mode=OneTime}"
                                SelectedValuePath="Value"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                SelectionChanged="PWMTyp_SelectionChanged"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Gebertyp}" />
                    <TextBox Visibility="{Binding GeberVisible}" Text="{Binding GeberNmr, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                   
                    <Slider   Visibility="{Binding WertVisible}" Value="{Binding Wert, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The code behind is:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       public ObservableCollection<PWMKanal> PWM_col { get; set; } = new();

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstPWM.ItemsSource = PWM_col;
            foreach (var item in Board.PWM)  PWM_col.Add(item); //Board.PWM is the data source.
        }
       private void PWMTyp_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;           // Finding the line in the ListBox.
            PWMKanal PWM = box.DataContext as PWMKanal;   
            int z = PWM_col.IndexOf(PWM);
            Board.PWM[z].Gebertyp = (QuellePWM)box.SelectedValue;
            if (Board.PWM[z].Gebertyp == QuellePWM.Sender)
            {
                PWM_col[z].GeberVisible = Visibility.Visible; // I thought that i may change the 
                PWM_col[z].WertVisible = Visibility.Hidden;   // ObservableColelction directly
             }                                                // but the display is not updated.
                else                                          // In Debug mode i see, that PWM_coll
             {                                                // is changed as expected, but no effect 
                PWM_col[z].GeberVisible = Visibility.Hidden;  // on the GUI.
                PWM_col[z].WertVisible = Visibility.Visible;
              }
              if (PWM_col.Count != 0) // this code is intended to update the GUI, but every time
              {                       // a new item is added the Selection Change fires again
                  PWM_col.Clear();    // and i get a stack overflow in an endless loop.
                  foreach (var item in Board.PWM) PWM_col.Add(item);
              }
            
        }
    }
```

The comments describe my approaches and problems:

1. I change the selected element of the `ObservableCollection` directly, but this has no effect on GUI. At least tho code doesn't crash.
2. I clear the list `ObservableCollection PWM_col`, but then i get an infinite loop: every time an element is added to the list the `SelectionChange` event fires, calling the routin again. Result is stack overflow.

Now my questions to my approaches:

1. Is it possible to change an element of an `ObservableCollection` directly by code, and the display is automatically refreshed?
2. Is it possible to somehow catch the `SelectionChanged` event before the handler is executed? Or is it possible to temporary dissable the event?
3. Any other idear?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello Bernd, welcome by StackOverflow. Next time avoid ask multiple questions in the post. This can help you with next questions : [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

1. `CollectionChanged` does notify, that collection itself, not the
   single items, is changed. Therefore to see the changes item's
   property need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also remove `Mode=OneTime`
2. You can of course set the flag, that `PWMTyp_SelectionChanged` is
   running:

   private bool selChangedIsRunning = false;
   private void PWMTyp_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
   if(selChangedIsRunning) return;
   selChangedIsRunning = true;
   // do stuff ....
   selChangedIsRunning = false;
   }
3. Other idea is - don't use the `SelectionChange` event, but do bind
   `Slider.Visibility` and `TextBox.Visibility` to the
   `ComboBox.SelectedValue` and use value converter to define the
   `Visibilty`, also you can use the `ConverterParameter`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbPWMTyp"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Gebertyp, Converter={local1:EnumToCollectionConverter}, Mode=OneTime}"
                    SelectedValuePath="Value"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                    SelectionChanged="PWMTyp_SelectionChanged"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Gebertyp}" />
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CmbPWMTyp, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}, ConverterParameter=TBX}" Text="{Binding GeberNmr, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Slider   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CmbPWMTyp, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}, ConverterParameter=SLDR}" Value="{Binding Wert, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This link can be also very helpful for you: [Difference between SelectedItem SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)