# cell editing combox databinding issue - WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have datagrid nested within a scrollviewer which accesses two seperate observable collections, one at the root level which is bound to the Datagrid items source "WallMaterials"  and the another which populates columns cell editing template via combox "NewWallMaterials" to update the values of the datagrid. Both collection types have properties which implement IPropertyChanged. However both collection types have properties called Name and Material and I have a suspicion that this is what's causing the problem.

That said, I want to be able to multi-set the "New Wall Material" for multiple rows based on the checkbox column on the first column. Therefore if the checkbox are checked, when I change the combobox on one rows it changes on all the rows where the checkbox ischecked.

When I run in debug mode its updates the properties, but when I try and move off the combobox and click on another combobox I get the following message:

"System.InvalidOperationExeception: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath"

xmal below

```
        <TextBlock  Text="Changes Material within wall compound" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial"></TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll_viewer" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
          
            <DataGrid x:Name="materialMapperDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding WallMaterials}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                      CanUserAddRows="False">

                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEA4B79"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16px"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Width="0.25">
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEA4B79"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <!--column 1-->
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectAll"
                                      IsThreeState="True"
                                      Checked="chkSelectAll_Checked"
                                      Unchecked="chkSelectAll_Unchecked"/>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="CheckBox_Click"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <!-- Column2 -->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wall Material" 
                                        Binding="{Binding Name}" 
                                        Width="*"
                                        >
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <!-- Column3 -->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="New Wall Material" Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewName}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.NewWallMaterials, RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                          SelectedValuePath="{Binding WallMaterials.NewName}"
                                          SelectedValue="Name"    
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectMaterial, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
        
    </ScrollViewer>
```

the window constructor is shown below.

```
    public ObservableCollection<WallMaterial> WallMaterials { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ProjectMaterial> NewWallMaterials { get; set; }
    private Document _doc = null;


    public WallMaterialChangerWindow(Document doc)
    {
        WallMaterials = new ObservableCollection<WallMaterial>();
        NewWallMaterials = new ObservableCollection<ProjectMaterial>();

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        _doc = doc;

    }
```

Combobox selection changed event below.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

        if (comboBox != null && comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            ProjectMaterial projectMaterial = comboBox.SelectedItem as ProjectMaterial;

            foreach (WallMaterial wallMaterial in WallMaterials)
            {
                if (wallMaterial.IsChecked)
                {
                   wallMaterial.NewName = projectMaterial.Name;
                   wallMaterial.NewMaterial = projectMaterial.Material;
                }
            }
            
        }

    }
```

Ay help will be greatly appreciated.

try to create a datagrid from two observable collections, one collection is used to update another.

Comment: Your `SelectedValuePath="{Binding WallMaterials.NewName}"` and `SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectMaterial, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` bindings look suspicious... I don't see any single object property named `WallMaterials` (there is a collection with this name, but collections typically don't have a `NewName` property) and I don't see any property named `ProjectMaterial` in your code. So where in your datacontext do you expect them to exist?

Comment: Also `SelectedValue="Name"` makes no sense. There should either be a Binding of the SelectedItem property or a Binding of SelectedValue with an appropriate value of the SelectedValuePath property. See here for how these properties work together: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4902039/1136211

Comment: If this is not your main application window you should also implement the properties you bind to as dependency properties to avoid a memory leak induced by the binding engine. Alternatively, configure the binding on the `ItemsSource` as `OneTime`. Usually, the property itself won't change as you would modify the existing collection instance. `OneTime` binding mode is the best solution in terms of performance.

Comment: Uff, Clemens is right, I was so focused on the strange content of the binding that I missed the complete misusage of SelectedValuePath vs SelectedValue. Generally speaking: do less things in one place... using all three of `SelectedValuePath`, `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` is almost certainly wrong.