# Display name from foreign Key constraint within a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, combobox

I have three tables. Employee, ClientEmp and Client.

ClientEmp has the `ForeignKey` of both Employee (EmployeeID) and Client(ClientID).

So far, I am able to save changes to ClientEmp in my database (using `EF`) based on the `selected` Client. But I have to type in the EmployeeID `ForeignKey` manually in a `textbox` to be able to match the data for it to save.

Obviously, this isn't very user friendly if a user has no idea what the EmployeeID FK is enter into the `textbox` either.

Therefore, is there a way to show a `list` of Employee Firstname's using a `combo box`  from the Employee table and then save it to the database?

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="cbEmployeeName" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employee}}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" 
          SelectedValuePath="EmployeeID">
</ComboBox>
```

I have also tried to use [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/184f6463-c5b0-49e5-87c2-5457adeb8243) and [This link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797034/confused-with-wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) to help but with no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I managed to figure it out with help from the [WPF Chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) and help from [Maverik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504757/maverik).

Within my xaml I defined the following;

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Employee"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type vm:ClientBookKeepingViewModel}"
                            MethodName="GetEmp">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
</ResourceDictionary>

<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="cbEmployeeName" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employee}}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" 
             SelectedValue="{Binding Path=EmployeeID}"
             SelectedValuePath="EmployeeID"
/>
```

and within my ViewModel, created this method to get a list of Employees;

```
public IEnumerable<DataObjects.Employee> GetEmp() 
{
    return context.Employees;
}
```