# how to load the foreign key values in WPF into a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, combobox, foreign-keys

I have a datatemplate controled control which is is being generated based on a EF collection of data which is set as the Datacontext  of this control. The template has a also a  combobox inside which should make it possible to change the foreign key value to another EF entityobject.

I am trying to load the foreign key collection from a viewModel

```
<my:EntryControlBase.Resources>
    <my:ModulesViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
</my:EntryControlBase.Resources>
```

This is the control in a datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="grdRoles" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

                <TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />


                *<ComboBox Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding   Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=ModulesCollection}"* >

                </ComboBox>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And the viewmodel code behind.

```
public class ModulesViewModel :DependencyObject
{
    public ModulesViewModel()
    {
        using(var context =new SPIS_Entities())
        {
            ModulesCollection = context.Module.Where(p => p.active).ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<Module> ModulesCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<Module>)GetValue(ModulesCollectionProperty);
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(ModulesCollectionProperty, value); 
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModulesCollectionProperty =
                        DependencyProperty.Register("ModulesCollection",
                                                    typeof(List<Module>),
                                                    typeof(ModulesViewModel),
                                                    null);
}
```

I was following a few examples from the internet, but I am having the whole time the problem that it can not find the "viewModel" ViewModel. it is set to *null*

The XAML definition of the viewmodel is set to the root of the usercontrol. Where ever I put it, it is underlined and null, saying "cannot create innstance ..." on mouse over. If I put it inside the combobox tags, it is still null, but not underlined

Suggestions?

Comment: I had a similar problem, take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416523/display-name-from-foreign-key-constraint-within-a-combobox Hope this helps concur your problem! :)

Comment: Where do you put the getEmp method. I see no code for the ViewModel.

Comment: Within your ViewModel, in your case the ModulesViewModel. Within that question, there are two links. Take a look through them as they might give you further help in regards to implementing what you are wanting to achieve :). Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem is that I my ViewModel is not being initialized

Comment: you are using the mvvm pattern right?

Comment: Do I need maybe to create an instance of the viewmodel in code manually?

Answer (score 0):

well in my solution I had a pretty simple codeline for that. I added a ListProperty for my foreign key value  and filled this list in the loadData() method of my business class.

```
        private void LoadData(ef.table data)
    {
        // method to set all the properties
        //this.example = data.example;
        LoadProperty<ForeignKeyClass>(ForeignKeyProperty, ForeignKeyClass.Get(data.efForeignKeyTable));
    }

    //Property
    public static readonly PropertyInfo<ForeignKeyClass> ForeignKeyProperty = RegisterProperty<ForeignKeyClass>(c => c.ForeignKeyPropertyName);
    public ForeignKeyClass ForeignKeyPropertyName
    {
        get { return GetProperty<ForeignKeyClass>(ForeignKeyProperty); }
        private set
        {
            SetProperty<ForeignKeyClass>(ForeignKeyProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

now u have got a property which is filled with the foreignKey data in your model. don't know if this is helping you but, this is how I get my foreignKey data into my Model. good luck