# Xaml ComboBoxItem equivalent for dropdownlist value property?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a Xaml ComboBoxItem equivalent for an HTML select value property?

```
<select>
    <option value=1>Test 1</option>
    <option value=2>Test 2</option>
    <option value=3>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Doesn't seem like there's a way to do that with Xaml?

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 3" />
</ComboBox>
```

Obviously, I'd like the user to select and option and then be able to pull the value (ID) for that selection to work with instead of having to do a lookup from the text/content value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Tag**:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 1" Tag="1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 2" Tag="2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 3" Tag="3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I did some reading on that property and it seems to be the "junk drawer" for whatever you want to use it for property.

Comment: Do you know how I would assign that programmatically?

Comment: Ahh - I think [this is what I'm looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797034/confused-with-wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use dropdownlist

`<dropdownlist >
Your options goes here 
<\dropdownlist>`