# C# WPF Datbinding - Why does WPF display the single letter instead of the content of a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF so I tried some tutorials. Now in my second project there is something that drives me crazy...

Here is the C# code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfDataBindingTest1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ICollection<TestClass> testClassCollection;
        public ICollection<TestClass> TestClassCollection
        {
            get { return this.testClassCollection; }
            set { if (this.testClassCollection != value) { this.testClassCollection = value; } }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.testClassCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>()
            {
                new TestClass() {ID = 1, Name = "Name1" },
                new TestClass() {ID = 2, Name = "Name2" },
                new TestClass() {ID = 3, Name = "Name3" }
            };
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDataBindingTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDataBindingTest1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox
            x:Name="lbTestClassItems"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source=TestClassCollection}">

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So when compiling and running this, I only get displayed each letter of the Word "TestClassCollection" in a new line in the listbox defined in the XAML file.

When adding `DisplayMemberPath="ID"` to the definition if the listbox, there is nothing displayed.

After some search I found this: [why is it displaying class name instead of property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604132/why-is-it-displaying-class-name-instead-of-property)

But this didn't helped.

Edit: Mysteriously if I do it via code (set itemsource and DisplayMemberPath), the correct data is displayed. But if I do it via XAML, see above

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use `Source` instead of `Path` in the `ItemsSource`?

Comment: You have to use a proper `ItemTemplate`. The listbox itself has no clue on how your bound items should display

Comment: @rbr94: same result, nothing is displayed

Comment: @lokusking I'll try it

Comment: @Radinator I just illustrate the propose of lokusking in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Path` instead of `Source` otherwise you're binding to string *TestClassCollection* hence your one letter per item. Ideally, if your item is a complex object, you would also either set `DisplayMemberPath` or use `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="lbTestClassItems" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestClassCollection}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Another problem is that you don't set `DataContext` anywhere. All binding work in binding context.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();        
    this.testClassCollection = ...;
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

**You need to do it in this other because your `MainWindow` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface** and `TestClassCollection` property does not raise `PropertyChanged` event. After that you can add/remove to `TestClassCollection` and it should be picked up by UI because `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface

Comment: thanks alot! this helped. :D just forgot to call `this.DataContext = this;`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbTestClassItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestClassCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Content="{Binding Id}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: sry but this does not help. now the listbox is gone

Answer (score 1):

You need a DataContext. Rather than having your "view model" code in the code behind for the main window, put it in a separate class. Like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.testClassCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>()
        {
            new TestClass() {ID = 1, Name = "Name1" },
            new TestClass() {ID = 2, Name = "Name2" },
            new TestClass() {ID = 3, Name = "Name3" }
        };
    }

    private ICollection<TestClass> testClassCollection;
    public ICollection<TestClass> TestClassCollection
    {
        get { return this.testClassCollection; }
        set { if (this.testClassCollection != value) { this.testClassCollection = value; } }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Then create an instance of the ViewModel class as the data context.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox
        x:Name="lbTestClassItems"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TestClassCollection}" >
        <ListBox.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </ListBox.DataContext>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I believe what is happening with your original implementation is that it is binding to the ToString of the property name. A string is considered a array of char, hence you get one letter per list item.

Ideally you probably wouldn't create a separate data context for the listbox. It would more likely inherit from it's parent. (i.e. the Window) But this illustrates the concept.