# SelectedValuePath does not return an id

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Hey I have a question about getting an ContactTypeId from the ContactType. This is the object that has an id:

```
public class ContactType
{
    public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }

    public string ContactTypeValue { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Added { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

}
```

I wrote a WPF application that has a listbox.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ContactTypeComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Margin="110,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="ContactTypeValue" SelectedValuePath="ContactTypeId"  />
```

If i get Selected value path doesn't give an ContactTypeId from that object. It only gives a string "ContactTypeId"

Please help me to get a ContactTypeId from ContactType

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797034/confused-with-wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath will benefit you.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedValuePath` tells the control how to drill down into the selected item and extract a value.  The value for the selected item (in this case, its `ContactTypeId`) is exposed as `SelectedValue`.  That's the property you want to read.